# Azure Search API/SDK Analyzer Attribute Alternative

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am setting up my Azure Search index using the API/SDK attributes. But I want to be able to change the Analyzer for a specific index based on an app setting (i.e. User sets language to French, so this index will use the French Analyzer).

Example of a couple of my index properties

```
    [IsSearchable]
    [Analyzer(AnalyzerName.AsString.EnMicrosoft)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable]
    [Analyzer(AnalyzerName.AsString.EnMicrosoft)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

I am setting the Analyzer to the Microsoft English one. But let's say I want to create another index, but this time using the Microsoft French Analyzer.

Is there a way to programmatically set this, apart from using an attribute? Some sort of event? OnIndexCreating etc... As it's restricting for more complex apps.

I can't have a separate field for each language either as I don't know what languages the user might choose.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your [Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.index?view=azuresearch-3.0.4) instance is created from a model class, you can access the list of [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.index.fields?view=azuresearch-3.0.4#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_Index_Fields) and change their [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.field?view=azuresearch-3.0.4), the [Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.field.analyzer?view=azuresearch-3.0.4#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_Field_Analyzer) is one of them.

```
var index = new Index()
{
    Name = "myindex",
    Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<MyModel>()
};

Field field = index.Fields.First(f => f.Name == "Title");
field.Analyzer = "fr.microsoft"; // There is an implicit conversion from string to AnalyzerName.
```

Alternatively, you can just build the `Field` instances yourself:

```
var index = new Index()
{
    Name = "myindex",
    Fields = new List<Field>()
    {
        new Field("Title", DataType.String, "fr.microsoft"),
        new Field("Description", DataType.String, "fr.microsoft")
    }
}
```

In both cases you can use a string for the analyzer name, which you could receive as user input or from config.

Comment: Sorry that's incorrect. " Once the analyzer is chosen, it cannot be changed for the field" that is from the Microsoft website.

Comment: Our documentation explains that the analyzer can't be changed on an existing field. From you question I understand, that you want to change the analyzer on a field of an index that you're programatically building but doesn't exist in the service yet. Is this not true?

Comment: As per the question. I want to use the same class but just change the Analyzer based on user input before the index is created.

Comment: You can do it by setting the analyzer property on the field.

Comment: Can you give me an example based on my question above please?

Comment: Thank you Bruce. Appreciate your time writing this answer.